# Functional way to extract object values given an array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

I have an array of key value pair objects that look likes below:

```
var d = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]
```

and an array

```
var a = ['a','e']
```

How do I write a function that extracts the value, essentially the result I want is

```
[{'name':'a', 'value':1},{'name':'e', 'value':5} ]
```

I want to write it in a pure functional way, and not using `for`, `while` loop, or `filter` function. I wonder is there a proper and effective way? Is recursive the right way?   I am open to using `lodash`, `ramda` or any other FP packages.

Comment: you mean `var a = ['a', 'e']`?

Comment: What is `[a,e]` supposed to be? `a` will be `undefined` at that point and `e` will throw a reference error. What have you tried? Looks like a job for `map` and `find`.

Comment: Are you matching on object references, or you want to match where name and value are equal?

Comment: Can we do it with recursive?

Comment: @cherhan see my answer. It is a recursive solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Array.prototype.map and Array.prototype.find**

It seems you're being stubborn about implementation details, but I'm certain you don't know why. There's nothing wrong with `for` or `while` or `filter`. By the end of this post, it's not my hope for you to *believe* me, instead it's my hope for you to *know* this to be true.

You can solve this problem trivially using `map` and `find` – for all intents and purposes, *how* `map` and `find` are implemented is mystery to you. It doesn't matter if they use a `for` loop or even a `GOTO` for crying out loud. What matters to you is that you get to express *your* problem in a functional way.

`map` and `find` are perfect companions to the humble JavaScript functional programmer...

```js
var d = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]

var a = ['a','e']

var result = a.map(x => d.find(y => y.name === x))

console.log(result)
// [ { name: 'a', value: 1 },
//   { name: 'e', value: 5 } ]
```

---

**generic functions promote code reuse**

Using some generic functions, we can express the solution in a slightly more reusable way

```js
var data = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]

const findBy = k => xs => v =>
  xs.find(x => x[k] === v)

const findAllBy = k => xs => vs =>
  vs.map(findBy(k)(xs))

console.log(findAllBy ('name') (data) (['a', 'e']))
// [ { name: 'a', value: 1 },
//   { name: 'e', value: 5 } ]
```

---

**why being stubborn doesn't help**

If you want to see how this is done without relying on *any* `for`, `while`, `filter`, `map`, or `find`...

```js
var data = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]

const main = ([x,...xs]) => {
  const aux = ([y,...ys]) => {
    if (y === undefined)
      return null
    else if (y.name === x)
      return y
    else
      return aux (ys)
  }
  if (x === undefined)
    return []
  else
    return [aux(data), ...main(xs)]
}

console.log(main(['a', 'e']))
// [ { name: 'a', value: 1 },
//   { name: 'e', value: 5 } ]
```

Pretty painful huh? And that code has less going on than other answers here that still have dependencies like `length`, `indexOf`, `slice` or the entire lodash lib.

So really it makes no sense to do this. There's tons of useful generic functions encoded within this example that we will want to use them in other places. That's why functions like `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and `find` exist in the first place – the same goes for `for` and `while`.

Every time I want to loop over an array, or filter an array, or find an element in an array, I don't want to do it by hand. The reason I use functions is so that I don't have to repeat myself... ever.

---

**curiosity**

So maybe you're OK with the `map`+`find` solution above, but you're also curious how you'd implement them on your own if you didn't have them at your disposal already – below are just 2 of *countless* ways in which you could implement either of these functions.

```js
var data = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]

const find = f => ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined ? null :
    f(x) === true ? x : find (f) (xs)

const map = f => ([x,...xs]) =>
  x === undefined ? [] : [f(x), ...map(f)(xs)]
  
const main =
  map (x => find (y => y.name === x) (data))
  
console.log(main(['a', 'e']))
// [ { name: 'a', value: 1 },
//   { name: 'e', value: 5 } ]
```

---

**recursion sucks in JavaScript**

Something a lot of people don't know about recursion in JavaScript is that it's actually not very good. We were promised tail call elimination in ES6 but no current implementation of JavaScript actually supports it yet. This means that any recursive function you write (unless you trampoline it) is at potential risk for a stack overflow.

This means implementing functional interfaces with `for` and `while` is *so* much better.

Below, we reimplement `map` and `find` but this time we do it in a smart way by avoiding the risk of a stack overflow. Notice it doesn't really have an effect on the resulting code. We can still interact with `map` and `find` in a nice, functional way – and they're both referentially transparent

Pay particular attention to the `main` function - it didn't change from the example above at all. Our "ugly" `while` and `for` loops were neatly hidden away as an implementation detail and the end user is none the wiser.

```js
var data = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]

const find = f => xs => {
  for (let x of xs)
    if (f(x) === true)
      return x
  return null
}

const map = f => xs => {
  const acc = Array(xs.length)
  for (let [i,x] of xs.entries())
    acc[i] = f(x)
  return acc
}

const main =
  map (x => find (y => y.name === x) (data))
  
console.log(main(['a', 'e']))
// [ { name: 'a', value: 1 },
//   { name: 'e', value: 5 } ]
```

Comment: Nice answer. Let's hope OP will take you seriously.

Comment: In general, pragmatism is a sane thing. We are pragmatic at work. Our code is pragmatic. There is nothing wrong with that. Except that it is pretty dull. There are many tags on SO where pragmatic answers are being asked and practical responses are given. Don't you think that the `functional-programming` tag is a little different in this regard. Does this tag not give us the opportunity to ask rather non-pragmatic questions? Questions about the aesthetics and elegance of code and the underlying reasoning? But of course you can use `for`/`of` et al. in your functions.

Comment: "_recursion sucks in JavaScript_" this is a short-lived statement. With Node.js I think, you can already benefit from TCO with the harmony flag, right?

Comment: @ftor well that's why I provided multiple answers – the reader can use any solution knowing its strengths and weaknesses. For awhile, I was promoting use of recursion in JavaScript under the pretense that tail call optimisation was right around the corner – now it seems like it will never see the light of day. If it's available in node, that's news to me (please link), but I'd still have to mention the stack overflow caveat until browsers are starting to get it

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}];
var a = ['a','e'];

d.filter(function(item){
  return a.indexOf(item.name) > -1; 
})

// will return [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':5}]
```

hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't that still loop?

Comment: @Vic I doubt there's a way to do that without looping. This is the closer we can get.

Comment: Which is why I find it so ridiculous. Why can't OP loop?

Comment: @Vic The OP wanted to avoid `for` and `while` loops specifically, since they’re not functional but imperative.

Comment: I learn something new everyday. Thanks @Xufox , I need to brush up.

Comment: Seems like recursion is what he wants?

Comment: Yes, can someone show me how to write in recursive?

Comment: @shakib I want the loop to stop as soon as I found everything I want.

Comment: Oh. Is that it? You just want the loop to stop?

Comment: how do you know when to stop? the last item may contain what you need.

Comment: @cherhan I've provided several recursive examples in my answer – but please read the entire answer to understand the pitfalls of using recursion in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I had to use `R.map`, but with `Ramda`:

```
R.flatten(R.map(R.useWith(R.filter, [R.propEq('name'), R.identity])(R.__, d), a))
```

This is what I could come up with, but I know there are better solutions which I'd love to hear about

---

**Edit**: I think this one is better

```
R.filter(R.compose(R.flip(R.contains)(a), R.prop('name')), d)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your solution to be recursive, you'd want something like this.

```js
function getValues(objects, names, result) {
  if (objects.length === 0 || names.length === 0) {
    return result;
  }
  var index = names.indexOf(objects[0].name)
  if (index > -1) {
    result.push(objects[0]);
    return getValues(objects.slice(1), [...names.slice(0, index), ...names.slice(index, names.length)], result);

  } else {
    return getValues(objects.slice(1), names, result);
  }
}

var d = [{'name':'a', 'value':1}, {'name':'b', 'value':2}, {'name':'c', 'value':3}, {'name':'d', 'value':4}, {'name':'e', 'value':5}, {'name':'f', 'value':6}]

var a = ['a','e']

console.log(getValues(d, a, []));
```

Comment: you're leaking private api with the `result` parameter – `getValues(d, a, ['foo'])` would yield a silly result – or worse, `getValues(d, a,   anyNonArrayValue)`. there's no reason to expose the result as a parameter.

Comment: If that's a concern you make an intermediate function that calls this one with empty array as third parameter. Not a big deal.

Comment: I understand how to fix it, the answer just feels incomplete as is – the unobservant learner might not see its harm and use this code verbatim

Answer (score -1):

I think the OP is looking for something like this:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

function solve(array, keys) {
    if (_.isEmpty(array) || _.isEmpty(keys)) {
        return [];
    } else {
        const [ele, ...tailArray] = array;
        const [key, ...tailKeys] = keys;

        if (ele.name === key) {
            return [ele, ...solve(tailArray, tailKeys)];
        } else {
            return solve(tailArray, keys);
        }
    }
}

const d = [{'name': 'a', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'value': 2}, {'name': 'c', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'd', 'value': 4}, {'name': 'e', 'value': 5}];
const a = ['a', 'e'];

console.log(solve(d, a));
```

This assumes that both arrays are sorted, all names are unique, and all elements in `array a` are also present in `array d`. Other solutions are left as an exercise for @cherhan.

Comment: Maybe someone cares to explain why this was downvoted?